# Design help: Akka clustering and dynamically created Actors

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

1. I have N nodes (i.e. distinct JREs) in my infrastructure running Akka (not clustered yet)
2. Nodes have no particular "role", but they are just processors of data. The "processors" of this data will be Actors. All sorts of non-Akka/Actor (other java code) (callers) can invoke specific types of processors by creating messages them data to work on. Eventually they need the result back.
3. A "processor" Actor is pretty simply and supports a method like "process(data)", they are stateless, they mutate and send data to an external system. These processors can vary in execution time so they are a good fit for wrapping up in an Actor.
4. There are numerous different types of these "processors" and the configuration for each unique one is stored in a database. Each node in my system, when it starts up, needs to create a router Actor that fronts N instances of each of these unique processor Actor types. I cannnot statically define/name/create these Actors hardwired in code, or akka configuration.
5. It is important to note that the configuration for any Actor processor can be changed in the database at anytime and periodically the creator of the routers for these Actors needs to terminate and recreate them dynamically based on the new configuration.
6. A key point is that some of these "processors" can only have a very limited # of Actor instances across all of my nodes. I.E processorType-A can have an unlimited number of instances, while processorType-B can only have 2 instances running across the entire cluster. Hence callers on NODE1 who want to invoke processorType-B would need to have their message routed to NODE2, because that node is the only node running processorType-B actor instances.

With that context in mind here is my question that I'm looking for some design help with:

- For points 1, 2, 3, 4 above, I have a good understanding of and implementation for
- For points 5 and 6 however I am not sure how to properly implement this with Akka clustering given that my "nodes" are not aware of each other AND they each run the same code to dynamically create these router actors based on that database configuration)

Issues that come to mind are:

- How do I properly deal with the "names" of these router Actors across the cluster? I.E for "processorType-A", which can have an unlimited number of Actor instances. Each node would locally have these instances available, yet if they are all terminated on a single node, I would still want messages for their "processor type" to be routed on to another node that still has viable instances available.
- How do I deal with enforcing/coordinating the "processor" instance limitation across the cluster (i.e. "processorType-B" can only have 2 instances globally) etc. While processorType-A can have a much higher number. Its like nodes need to have some way to check with each other as to who has created these instances across the cluster? I'm not sure if Akka has a facility to do this on its own?

ClusterRouterPool? w/ ClusterRouterPoolSettings?

Any thoughts and/or design tip/ideas are much appreciated! Thanks